# Disabling email capabilities on dedicated server

Tags: linux, centos, email, email-server, disk-space-utilization

I have a dedicated server that doesn't need to use email on any account, and I found that the disk is getting full often. I use to fix it removing domlogs and some apache logs but now that didn't solved it so I searched what was using the most space on disk and found that the folders `/home/user/mail/new/` is full of files, I removed those folders from a few users and now the disk is not full anymore.

**How can I disable email capabilities so those folders wont get full of files anymore?**

The server doesn't even have an email address configured on any account so I assume it's all spam from some catch-all address.

Comment: Are there any mail folders there now? Can you look at them to see what sort of mail it is? It could be the server itself notifying the user. Are there any management software packages running to configure services, or is the mailserver, webserver, etc maintained by hand?

Comment: How about removing/uninstalling any email related packages/services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of your users, you can simply use your server's Yum and RPM package management tools to remove all of the email tools.

You'll want to make sure things like Exim, Fetchmail, Mailx, and 'mail-utils' packages are removed.

This won't take care of folks who are savvy enough to upload their own packages and compile them, but this should take care of most users. If you really feel the need to restrict it further, I'd suggest blocking outgoing connections for all the common posts used by email protocols using IPTables or System-config-firewall.

I'm a command-line guy, so I'd be using 'rpm -qa' and grep to look for the common tools. The CentOS GUI package manager may also be helpful in presenting a list of what packages are available and/or already installed.

Comment: The server is only managed by me, all the accounts are mine so removing the email packages should work, now I need to figure out what package is being use, i guess exim since it's a common centos server.

Comment: My bad. I thought the question said Ubuntu. Will fix it to reference CentOS/RHEL tools.